# STM32 CDC byte transfer

Tags: usb, stm32, cdc, hal, stm32f4

comrades!
I've trying to write kind of protocol above USB CDC on F405 controller. Idea is very simple - form on host some message consists of bits determined by required hardware configuration and send them to MCU. On MCU side split incoming message for bytes and then make some stuff according to received data.
BUT
Data in Rx buffer present like symbols, not like bytes. So if i send 0xFF, for example, i've got "FF" in MCU buffer. Two bytes instead of four. An i should convert each symbol to hex value. With complex messages it may cause weird bugs. That's should work, but... I think that simplier solution should exist to split message for bits. Maybe i've miss something in USB setup?

Comment: all data is bits. No data is hex. Hex is a human representation of bits. Nothing to do with computers.

Comment: @P__J__ ,  of course. my question about representation. 0xF and "F" different in bits, so "bit meaning" of data from host is not equal to data received by mcu

Comment: I afraid |I do not understand. What bit meaning?

Comment: @P__J__ , i've just notice that my terminal app send only symbols, so when i make simple app that send exactly bytes instead of ascii everything becomes okay